# Who is responsible for clean up of grpc::ServerUnaryReactor when using callback grpc service

Tags: grpc-c++

I am trying to implement grpc callback service and have derived my callback handler class from ServerUnaryReactor.

`class AuthorisationCallbackHandler : public grpc::ServerUnaryReactor`

As part of request processing we return grpc::ServerUnaryReactor* to grpc server/service.

```
grpc::ServerUnaryReactor* NetworkTrustCallbackService::CreateTrust(
    ::grpc::CallbackServerContext* context,
    const ::networktrust::v1::CreateTrustRequest* request,
    ::networktrust::v1::CreateTrustResponse* responsePtr
)
{
    const auto deviceId = request->ed25519_pk();
    auto handlerPtr = std::make_unique<AuthorisationCallbackHandler>(_auth, deviceId);
    return handlerPtr.release();
}
```

The destructor for AuthorisationCallbackHandler is never called so I assume we are still responsible for its clean up.

Is this correct and how to we know grpc is finished with it?

Is that what grpc::ServerUnaryReactor::OnDone is for?

Comment: Did you ever find out the answer to this? Working on the basis of the route_guide example, and looking at the "class Lister : public grpc::ServerWriteReactor<Feature>" that's used in the ListFeatures RPC, I've assumed that OnDone() is where you need to delete 'yourself'. I found your question while searching for the same understanding; pity there's been no definitive answer.